# Writing operation fails - firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following object:

```
const offer = {
  offerInfo: {
    price: '',
    status: 'open',
    message: '',
    ownerUID: '',
    ownerName: '',
    ownerPhoto: '',
    ownerAvgRating: '',
    ownerReviewNumber: '',
  },
  offerMetaData: {
    userHasSeenOffer: false,
    userHasBeenNotified: false,
  }
}
```

I am trying to post it to the following node:

`updates['jobs/${activeJob.key}/offers/${currentUser.uid}] = offer;`
 and then `firebase.database().ref().update(updates)`

As you can see I am using the users uid as the id of the offer itself.

Now when I try to post it using the following rules, I get a permission denied error and I have no clue why.

Rules:

```
"jobs": {
  "$job_uid": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    "job": {
      ".write": "!data.exists() && root.child('allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/paymentDetails').exists() || data.exists() && root.child('jobs/' + $job_uid + '/job/owner').val() === auth.uid",
    },
    "offers": {
      "$offer_uid": {
        "offerInfo": {
          ".write": "$offer_uid === auth.uid",
        },
        "offerMetaData": {
          ".write": "root.child('jobs/' + $job_uid + '/job/owner').val() === auth.uid || $offer_uid === auth.uid",
        },
      },
    },
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write directly to `$offer_uid` but you don't have any write rules on that node so it will use the default false.

For you current write to succeed you can change your rules like this:

```
"$offer_uid": {
    ".write": "$offer_uid === auth.uid",
    "offerMetaData": {
      ".write": "root.child('jobs/' + $job_uid + '/job/owner').val() === auth.uid",
    },
  },
```

I moved the write rule one node up, directly in `$offer_uid`, instead of having it in both the childs seperatly.

Another option would be to keep your rules and split your write so you are writing to the child nodes.

Comment: One more question! I thought rules would cascade meaning that the first write rule would override the second one?

Comment: @WalterMonecke What rules exactly are you talking about?